# How to create a PDF from a string and send it to the user?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, pdf

Good morning everybody,

I have a project which is supposed to be deployed on

sharepoint 2007 (wss 3.0) as a custom web part . It is

simply a button to convert a certain string to a pdf

file and send it to the user.I'm using c# .NET . I have

the following code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader"ContentDispositio
n", "attachment;filename=foo.pdf");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bb.Length.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bb);
```

bb is a bytes array.
And this is working fine regarding the "sending the file

to user" part.

The problem I'm facing is with the creation of the bytes

array. I don't know how to create a bytes array from a

string that could be converted to PDF. I tried using

iTextSharp, but for some reason i'm always facing an

error with this line:

Document d = new Document();

The web part gives me an error when it's deployed (File

not found).

Now i'm stuck. What is the appropriate way to convert

this string to pdf and send it to the user WITHOUT

STORING IT ANYWHERE!

Any help is highly appreciated & thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you clarify: your issue is not how to create a byte array from a stream, but how to convert a text string into a pdf byte array?

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps in creating the byte array, i am using html parser to convert my xml document to pdf -

```
// Using iTextSharp to construct a PDF document
            // Create a document-object
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

            // Create a writer that listens to the document
            // and directs a XML-stream to a MemoryStream
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
                document.Open();


                System.Xml.XmlTextReader _xmlr;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMsg))
                    _xmlr = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new StringReader(GetTransferedData(content)));
                else
                    _xmlr = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new StringReader(@"<html><body>Error Message:" + errorMsg + "</body></html>"));
                iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlParser.Parse(document, _xmlr);
                document.Close();                 
                ms.Flush();
                byte[] data = ms.ToArray();

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.BinaryWrite(data);
                Response.End();
                ms.Close();
            }
```