# How to output XML from web page

Tags: asp.net, xml

I'm building a web forms app with VSE 2012 and VB that transforms XML (will be uploaded by user) to another XML using XSL and need to allow the user to view/save the transformed doc. I'd like to display the result on screen (as raw XML so it can copied and pated) and offer the ability to download vs. Copy and paste

I've got the transform working but can't figure out how to display as raw XML or give user ability to download. This is what I have so far. It displays the results but only displays contents of nodes, not raw XML:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
           Handles Me.Load
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml"

    'Dim transformedfile As String

    Dim xsltFile As String = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, _
        "Test.xsl")
    Dim xmlFile As String = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "XMLDoc.xml")

        Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform() 'Pass in true to enable XSLT Debugging
        xslt.Load(xsltFile)

        Dim doc As New XPathDocument(xmlFile)
    xslt.Transform(doc, New XmlTextWriter(Response.Output))
```

Thanks in advance

mark

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a page with content type "text/xml" to the user's browser.  (The browser will determine what to do with this page;  you can give it hints with a content disposition header of "inline" or "attachment").

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962981/how-to-create-a-pdf-from-a-string-and-send-it-to-the-user) shows how to do this when returning a PDF file;  you're just sending an XML content type, like:

```
byte[] data = memorystream.ToArray();

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.BinaryWrite(data);
Response.End();
```

I hope this helps.